# Problem with writing data to the database

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

I work in Blazor (C #). I have a problem with writing data to the database when registering a user. I used add-migration and update-database, so an empty Users table was created for me. I tried to write various functions with savechanges (), but to no avail. Below I send the code I wrote so far:

Here are the various functions with savechanges () that I was trying to write.

Users.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestBlazor.Models;

namespace TestBlazor.Data
{

    //public interface IToDoListService
    //{
    //    Task<User> Add(User user);
    //}

    public class Users
    {
        //public static void AddUsers()
        //{
        //    var user = new User { Url = "" };
               //context.User.Add(user);
               //context.SaveChanges();
        //}

        private readonly AppDbContext _dataContext;

        public Users(AppDbContext dataContext)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext;
        }

        //public static void AddUsers()
        //{
        //    //var user = new User { Url = "" };
        //    _dataContext.User.Add(User);
        //    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
        //}

        //public void Save()
        //{
        //    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
        //}

        //public async Task<User> Add(User user)
        //{
        //    _dataContext.User.Add(user);
        //    await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        //    return user;
        //}

        //[HttpPost]
        //public void Add([FromBody] User user)
        //{
        //    _dataContext.User.Add(user);
        //    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
        //}

        //[HttpPost]
        //public void Add(User user)
        //{
        //    //Determine the next ID
        //    var newID = _dataContext.User.Select(x => x.UserId).Max() + 1;
        //    user.UserId = newID;

        //    _dataContext.User.Add(user);
        //    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
        //    //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //}

        public void AddUser(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                _dataContext.User.Add(user);
                _dataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the connection to the database.

AppDbContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestBlazor.Models;

namespace TestBlazor.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext()
        {

        }

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=testblazor;Integrated Security=True;");
            }
        }

        //protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        //{
        //    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        //}

        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }


    }

}
```

Here is the data model.

User.cs:

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestBlazor.Models
{
    [Table("Users")]
    public class User
    {
        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "UserName is required.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "password must be atleast 8 characters")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Company")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company is required.")]
        [Remote("doesCompanyExist", "Company", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Company already exists. Please enter a different company.")]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        public User GetRegisteredUser()
        {
            return new User
            {
                UserName = UserName,
                Password = Password,
                Email = Email,
                Company = Company,

            };
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the registration layout.

Register.razor:

```
@page "/register"

@using TestBlazor.Models
@using TestBlazor.Data

@*@inject IToDoListService user*@

<br />
<br />

<h3><b>Register</b></h3>
<br />

<EditForm class="needs-validation" Model="@_user" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit">
    <div class="alert @StatusClass">@StatusMessage</div>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>User name</b></p>
        <input id="username" class="solid" name="username" placeholder="Your username.." @bind-value="_user.UserName" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.UserName)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Password</b></p>
        <input type="password" class="solid" id="password" placeholder="Your password.." @bind-value="_user.Password" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Password)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Email</b></p>
        <input id="email" class="solid" placeholder="you@example.com" @bind-value="_user.Email" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Email)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Company</b></p>
        <input id="company" class="solid" placeholder="Your company.." @bind-value="_user.Company" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Company)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>


    <br />

    <button disabled="@loading" class="btn btn-primary">

        @if (loading)
        {
            <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
            <NavLink href="/login" class="btn btn-link">Register</NavLink>
        }
        Register
    </button>
    <NavLink href="/login" class="btn btn-link">Login</NavLink>
</EditForm>



@code {
    private User _user = new User();

    private string StatusMessage;
    private string StatusClass;

    private bool loading;


    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        if (loading == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have successfully registered!");
        }

        else
        {
            loading = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Check your information again!");
        }
    }

    protected void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        StatusClass = "alert-info";
        StatusMessage = " You have successfully registered! Please click the Login button to log in!";
    }

    protected void HandleInvalidSubmit()
    {
        StatusClass = "alert-danger";
        StatusMessage = " Check your information again!";
    }


    public bool doesCompanyExist(string Company)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Company != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

Here are the pictures:

[The image shows an empty base.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srjTo.png)

[The figure shows the added columns in the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnklF.png)

[The image shows the information I am trying to enter when registering.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy99J.png)

Comment: And not a single error message or accurate statement of what problem you're hitting

Comment: It doesn't throw out any error to me, but the data in the database is not recorded when I enter the data during user registration.

Comment: Well, you code won't show any errors if you just put `return false` in your `catch(Exception)` blocks. You're the only one who can debug this; throwing your exceptions away is the best way of crippling any ability to understand what is going wrong (remove your try catches)

Comment: Also, where is the code that actually performs the save.. ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the Users.cs class, I tried to write.

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to contain any code that interacts with a database, at all? Which lines of code that you have posted, do you think will load or save something?

Comment: Saving code in the Users.cs class. There I tried to save the data using the SaveChanges () function.

Comment: Yes, but where do you call AddUser?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not calling her anywhere. I wonder, should I create a Controller?

Comment: That rather depends on if it's Blazor Web assembly (yes) or Blazor Server (probably not)

Comment: This is a Blazor server. How then would it be best to resolve this? I’m new to this, so I’m still not doing my best.

Comment: If it's server I would say that it doesn't really matter for now, just make sure you're actually calling AddUser at some point